# what is (step,tick,timer,start,stop,speeds) properties in fx object in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is (step,tick,timer,start,stop,speeds) properties in fx object in jquery? 
Please see the example below.

for(fxProperties in $.fx){
    document.write(fxProperties + '
')
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are simply internals used by jQuery for animation effects

For example if you use `'slow'` for  duration in an animation like `slidetoggle('slow')` it gets the numeric value from `$.fx.speeds.slow` which is `600`